# Count word occurances in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, count

I'm currently working on a Wordpress plugin that will count the number of times particular keywords occur throughout the blog posts and add them up.  For example, if the keywords are 'ghost', 'chair', and 'thumb' and they each occur 4 times throughout the blog, it will return the number 12.

I've tried tackling with PHP and MySQL, and I'm stuck both ways.  Any advice?

Comment: Please let us know what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

About 3 seconds of googling for something like "php str count" would reveal the answer: [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

```
$content = ''; // fill with your content
$words = array('ghost', 'chair', 'thumb');
$count = 0;
foreach ($words as $word) {
  $count += substr_count($content, $word);
}
echo $count;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Jeremy... I'm still doing something wrong.  

$query = "SELECT post_content FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$content = $result;$words = array('ghost', 'chair', 'thumb');
$count = 0;
foreach ($words as $word) {
$count += substr_count($content, $word);
}
echo $count;`

gives me:

**Warning: substr_count() expects parameter 1 to be string**

 Also, my apologies, I apparently can't figure out formatting on here.

Comment: Look at the [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) docs and you'll find that it returns a query, not a string. Hence the error. Look into how to read the results on that page.

Comment: Got it all figured out now, thanks for your help!

Comment: Cool glad you got it working! Make sure to mark it as answered so others know it's answered.